# Xcode 7 is using my framework after I deleted it

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks

I'm in the process of developing a framework. My problem is that the changes I make to my framework are not being reflected in my app. My app seems to be linked to the original framework I created and isn't updating when I update the framework. Even when I delete the framework from my project, xcode still seems to think it's there.

**Setup** 
I created a separate xcode project intending to make an app that uses the framework. I copied the root folder of my framework project into my app project root folder and I drag and dropped the .xcodeproj into my App's xcode project. I added the framework from my nested xcode project in each of the following steps:

1. Build Phases>Link Binary With Libraries
2. Build phases>Target Dependencies
3. General>Embedded Binaries

I tried removing the framework from each of these locations.
I tried cleaning the framework project and App project.
I tried deleting the derived data in my app project and framework project in Window>Projects
I tried using a previous version of my app project that doesn't contain the framework in any way (not in the xcode project or root folder)

The ghost of my framework continues to haunt my project! Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made a mistake.

I was using the classes I built my framework out of rather than the framework itself. I thought deleting these classes and selecting 'Remove Reference' would stop Xcode from using them. I deleted these classes completely and Xcode told me they couldn't find the class I was looking for-- indicating it was using those files rather than the framework.

Also, in my AppDelegate I used

```
import "ExternalClass.h"
```

Which I believe is for classes that are in the project. I changed this to

```
import <ExternalClass/ExternalClass.h>
```

to import the header file from the framework instead.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you must have tried deleting it from build phases as well... just in case though:

1. Go to Build phases -> Link Binary with libraries
2. Select the one you want to remove, press minus button down there.

Do it for all modules: as in Debug, Release.

You can also try deleting the older framework and emptying trash to be on the safer side.

Comment: Thanks KP_G for your answer. Turns out I wasn't using the framework at all but I was using the classes I build my framework from. I upvoted your answer because you gave me the idea to see if deleting these classes completely would help. Thanks!